# showing gridview after button pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to show the gridview after the button is pressed. 
Here is my code regarding the view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Lounge No" HeaderText="Lounge No" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Lounge No" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Film Name" HeaderText="Film Name" SortExpression="Film Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="Time" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_Description" HeaderText="Type_Description" SortExpression="Type_Description" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And this is what i have in the code for the button:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource3.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: are you hiding the gridview before you press this button? question is unclear can you explain it a bit better. in the code for the button you're just binding the data. is the id of your gridview called SqlDataSource3?

Comment: you are going to need to show a heck of a lot more also if this is an `Asp.Net web app` you will need to understand `PostBacks` and that they are triggered automatically on button clicks in asp.net web apps read up on `Asp.net page life cycle as well` you need to check `if(Is.PostBack){ } else { }` and do some binding using static datatable for example please show all relevant code when you edit this so we can see what it is you are currently doing..

Comment: your button click is useless as binding a datasource is not your objective.  you need to bind the datasource to the gridview, so... `GridView1.DataBind()`.  However, you also have this: `GridView1.DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"` which, assuming your gridview is not hidden and the data source is properly configured, should fill `GridView1`when you display the page

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Visible="false" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Lounge No" HeaderText="Lounge No" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="Lounge No" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Film Name" HeaderText="Film Name" SortExpression="Film Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="Time" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Type_Description" HeaderText="Type_Description" SortExpression="Type_Description" />
</Columns>
```

Add Visible="false" attribute to gridview.

code for Button click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if (GridView1.Visible == false)
      {
            SqlDataSource3.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            Button1.Text = "Hide";
      }
      else
      {
           GridView1.Visible = false;
           Button1.Text = "Show";
      }
}
```